# Bash: manipulating with strings (percent sign)

Tags: string, bash, parameters

What does a percent sign mean in bash when manipulating strings? For example, what does `${0%/*}` mean?

Comment: You can check it in http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664

Comment: New link to "String Operations" docs: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22828

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.

Comment: This question should be marked a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34951901 instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you use @fedorqui's resource, you'll see it is going to strip the shortest match of `/*` from the end of the first positional argument. An example:

```
example_foo(){
    echo ${1%/*}
}

example_foo path/to/directory/sub_directory
# => path/to/directory
```

In the example I used the second positional argument since the first is the name of the function.

Comment: To address the original question, `$0` is the full pathname of the script being executed; the given expression strips off the final component of the path, so it is roughly equivalent to `dirname $0`.

Comment: As I understand it, the `1` in the example indicates the second fragment of the command, counting from 0.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco that is correct. You might also hear "fragment" referred to as "argument" though.

Comment: Is that ${1} a reference to the stdin? And can I pipe things into it?

Comment: @Tom, $1 refers to `path/to/directory/sub_directory` which is the 1st argument to `example_foo`. You cannot pipe things into it.

Comment: Quotes are important. `echo ${1%/*}` can show incorrect output in cases where `echo "${1%/*}"` is correct; consider, for instance, following `set -- '*/foo'` -- the former will list files in the current directory.