# What is the value of ${variable%rc*}?

Tags: string, bash

I've come across this curious bash expression:

```
somestring=4.5.6
echo ${somestring%rc*}
```

For all that I can tell it just prints `4.5.6`. So why would anybody use it?

I found it in [this](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/python&id=b56cfc026bbef6df1dcb975afd7a518f139b3189) script (look for `pkgver`), so I hope I didn't miss any context which is necessary for this to work.

Comment: Read the [Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), it's long but will tell you all you need to know. In your case, the [expansion chapter](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION) contains the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Source:](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)*

> `${string%substring}` deletes shortest match of `$substring` from back of
>   `$string`.

The intention is to echo the numerical version only, without the `rc*` suffix for strings like:

```
somestring=4.5.6rc1
somestring=4.5.6rc23_whatever
```

---

<sup>***UPDATE:***</sup>
*The better choice is to* `echo ${somestring%%rc*}`.
*Otherwise, the following might happen:*

```
somestring=4.5.6rc1_rc2
echo ${somestring%rc*}
4.5.6rc1_
```

*whereas:*

```
echo ${somestring%%rc*}
4.5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

It removes `rc` and any following characters (the `*`) from `somestring`.  See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16444004/2877364).

Answer (score 0):

This is known as parameter expansion.

From [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${parameter%word}
>
> ${parameter%%word}
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>   value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of
>   parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’
>   or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
>   parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If
>   parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

---

Simply `"${somestring%rc*}"` is the string left by cutting `rc*` (`*` means anything after `rc`) from `$somestring` from right i.e `rc*` is matched in the string from right and then deleted and the resultant is the remaining string.