# what does "%" mean in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I was going through some shell scripts, and I came across (for the first time) the use "%", some thing like:

```
build/audio/base/%.wav: src-audio/%.wav
```

I do not know what it is supposed to mean. Is it some thing like "*"?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the context?  it may be intended for string substitution would be my first guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: manipulating with strings (percent sign)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444004/bash-manipulating-with-strings-percent-sign)

Comment: What language and platform are you asking about? Because that doesn't look like bash.

Comment: That is probably a [`Makefile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples).

Comment: @Kenney Yes, it is a make file, I was told Makefiles are basically shell scripts.. am I misinformed?

Comment: @ClaytonSmith yes, looks like string substitution, but I am not sure, how it works, I can't find anything in the code which would tell it, substitute % by "xyz"

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, hmm, it is a Makefile, aren't they actually shell scripts?

Comment: A makefile is not anything like a shell script.

Comment: A shell script is too vague of a term on UNIX/Linux, because there's many kinds of shells. Most shell scripts you'll find are bash scripts, and they have something like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` as their first line. It can also be `#!/usr/bin/perl`, in which case it is a perl script (which is not a shell), etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is from a makefile, not a shell script. From [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match):

> A target pattern is composed of a ‘`%`’ between a prefix and a suffix, either or both of which may be empty. The pattern matches a file name only if the file name starts with the prefix and ends with the suffix, without overlap. The text between the prefix and the suffix is called the stem. Thus, when the pattern ‘`%.o`’ matches the file name `test.o`, the stem is ‘`test`’. The pattern rule prerequisites are turned into actual file names by substituting the stem for the character ‘`%`’. Thus, if in the same example one of the prerequisites is written as ‘`%.c`’, it expands to ‘`test.c`’.

So every file that matches "build/audio/base/*.wav" has a dependency of "src-audio/*.wav" where the two parts that are represented by "*" must match.

Comment: Yes, it is a makefile, while I am at it, can you also tell me what does ":" mean here? you mentioned something about dependency. can you elaborate? Thanks!